# How to add user and group without a password using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to add group and user without password (nologin user) using Ansible script.

I execute the following command:

```
$ansible-playbook deploy_nagios_client.yml -i hosts -e hosts=qa1-jetty -v
```

Below is `main.yml`

```
---

# Create Nagios User and Group 
  - name: Add group "nagios"
    group: name=nagios
    become: true

  - name: Add user "nagios"  
    user: name=nagios groups=nagios password="" shell=/bin/bash append=yes comment="Nagios nologin User" state=present
    become: true
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcT54.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create user with option --disabled-password by Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013796/create-user-with-option-disabled-password-by-ansible)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to create a nologin user, you should specify that to the `shell` argument like this:

```
  - name: Add user "nagios"  
    user:
      name: nagios
      groups: nagios
      shell: /sbin/nologin
      create_home: no
      append: yes
      comment: "Nagios nologin User"
      state: present
    become: true
```

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, adding a user with the user module does what you want if you leave off the password attribute entirely.

Comment: No, it does not. Calling `ansible.builtin.user` module without the password attribute will create the user with a `!` in `/etc/passwd`, locking the account. In order to have a truely empty password, you must add `password: ''`.

Comment: I haven't had to touch Ansible in a few years, but I'm pretty sure it was accurate when I wrote it. I had spent quite a bit of time fuddling with user creation in deployment scripts. If indeed the functionality has changed, it might be worth posting this as a new, separate answer.