# Create user with option --disabled-password by Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, ansible

On Ubuntu 14.04 I creating user with disabled password like:

> sudo adduser --disabled-password myuser

I need to do same with Ansible [user](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html)  module

> --disabled-password

Similiar option in Ansible documentation is missing. Could somebody help me, how can I get the same result with user module?

Comment: I suspect that omitting password parameter for `user` module is what you want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) module use `useradd` command [under the hood](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/system/user.py#L317).
If you omit `password` parameter for `user` module, ansible calls `useradd` without `-p` flag.
Man page of useradd states:

> -p, --password PASSWORD
> The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.

This is exactly what is needed by OP.

Comparison of `adduser --disabled-password test1` and `- user: name=test2 state=present`:

```
# grep test /etc/shadow
test1:*:17031:0:99999:7:::
test2:!:17031:0:99999:7:::
# passwd -S test1
test1 L 08/18/2016 0 99999 7 -1
# passwd -S test2
test2 L 08/18/2016 0 99999 7 -1
```

As you see in both cases passwords are locked.

Comment: I've created a user via ansible user module without specifying a password and when I run chage -l on that user it shows me their password will expire in a year.  So if you create a user this way you risk your ssh process failing in a year when the non-existent password expires, especially if your connecting programmatically to the user with a program that won't know how to handle a password reset prompt.

Comment: as of ansible 2.11 a passwd_expire_max argument exists which can be set to -1 to avoid issues with disable password still expiring.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between `test1` and `test2` of this answer.
 On my machine (debian 11): 
 - test2 account is locked even for ssh public key authentication. 
 - test1 would be able to login via ssh using public key authentication

Answer (score 4):

Since Ansible 2.6 the `user` module has the option [`password_lock`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html#parameter-password_lock), which will run `usermod -L` (Linux), `pw lock` (FreeBSD), or `usermod -C` (?):

`usermod -L`:

> Lock a user's password. This puts a '!' in front of the encrypted password, effectively disabling the password.

`pw lock`:

> The pw utility supports a simple password locking mechanism for users; it works by prepending the string `*LOCKED*` to the beginning of the password field in master.passwd to prevent successful authentication.

So you could use:

```
- name: Create password locked user
  user:
    name: myuser
    state: present
    password_lock: yes
```

Comment: I needed to create system account which does not use password, so I was able to do `su - username` without password prompt. If I understand it correctly, this will create locked user account, into which I will not be able to log in or not?

Comment: @32cupo this will only prevent the user from being able to login with a password, it will still be able to login via SSH keys or `su` from another user.

Answer (score 1):

This was a little different for me. I wanted to become the user with `su username`, but after trying [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39018859/10145562) I was still being prompted for a password that had never been set.

Steps tried:

- Leaving off the password
- Setting `shell: /sbin/nologin` inside the "Create app user" task

My solution was to add a shell step in my Ansible playbook to disable the user's password, but keep access to the shell. Now the account status is `NP` for no password instead of `L` for locked. I am able to login with `su` command without being prompted for a password.

```yaml
---
- hosts: todo
  become_user: root
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Create app group
      ansible.builtin.group:
        name: "{{ gh_repo }}"
        state: present
        system: true

    - name: Create app user
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ username }}"
        home: /home/{{ username }}/
        state: present
        system: true
        group: "{{ username }}"

    - name: Disable user password
      shell: |
        passwd -d {{ gh_repo }}
```

You can view your account's status with `sudo passwd --status username`.